# Simplificar un script de google sheets

Tags: script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Antes que nada quiero decir que no entiendo nada de programación, y todo lo que hago es buscando información por internet.
Estoy haciendo una hoja de cálculo para el control de criptomonedas, y tengo un código que me importa los precios a tiempo real de todos mis tokens. El código en sí funciona correctamente, pero en el ejemplo que adjunto apenas tengo 5 monedas, y en total debo poner más de 50, por lo que el código se puede hacer muy extenso.

La pregunta es, ¿se puede simplificar de alguna forma, que no deba escribir tantas líneas de código?

```
function CopyData() {

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var cotitzacions = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Cotitzacions");
  var fullMes = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Gener1");
  
  var lc = fullMes.getLastColumn()+1
  var date = new Date();
  var astro = cotitzacions.getRange("C39").getValue();
  var avax  = cotitzacions.getRange("C11").getValue();
  var axs   = cotitzacions.getRange("C15").getValue();
  var b2m   = cotitzacions.getRange("C34").getValue();
  var btc   = cotitzacions.getRange("C6").getValue();


  var ddate = fullMes.getRange(1,lc);
  var dastro =  fullMes.getRange(2,lc);
  var davax = fullMes.getRange(6,lc);
  var daxs = fullMes.getRange(10,lc);
  var db2m = fullMes.getRange(14,lc);
  var dbtc = fullMes.getRange(18,lc);

  ddate.setValue(date);
  dastro.setValue(astro);
  davax.setValue(avax);
  daxs.setValue(axs);
  db2m.setValue(b2m);
  dbtc.setValue(btc);

}
```

Espero que me puedan ayudar. Muchas gracias

Comment: Puedes compartir un ejemplo de como luce el Google sheets con las 50? Para probar la solución antes de enviarla :)

Comment: Un usuario del soporte de google me ha aportado una solución que cumple a la perfección lo que necesito. De todos modos Muchas gracias por tu interés @SMN947 
Comparto la respuesta por si le puede servir a alguien más.

Answer (score 0):

Comparto la respuesta que me ha enviado un usuario de la pàgina oficial de soporte Google Docs Help. El usuario es Jean-Pierre Verhulst

```
function copyData() {
const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
const cotitzacions = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Cotitzacions");
const fullMes = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Gener1");
const lc = fullMes.getLastColumn()+1;
const values = cotitzacions.getRange("C:C").getValues().filter( (r, i) => [39, 11, 15, 34, 6].includes(i + 1) )
values.unshift(new Date());
[1, 2, 6, 10, 14, 18].forEach((r, i) => fullMes.getRange(r, lc).setValue(values[i]))
}
```

Espero que les pueda servir a alguien más.